# Каков принцип работы метода compareTo()?

Tags: java, сравнение

Кто может объяснить принцип сравнения, когда есть разные варианты сравниваемых строк, которые могут отличаться как буквами, так и длиной?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Строки в Java(и вообще много где) сравниваются с помощью [Лексикографического порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA). О том, что это такое можно почитать так же [тут](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA). Общий смысл, по алфавиту.

Если говорить именно про класс `String`, то он реализует интерфейс [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) в документации подробно описано, что должен возвращать метод `compareTo()`. Если вкратце, то он определяет порядок элементов.

`o1.compateTo(o2)`:

> 0 - если o1 должен идти после o2 (в случаем с числами `o1>o2`, со строками, по алфавиту o2 идёт раньше o1)

=0 - если o1 и o2 равнозначны (не обязательно равны! НО, если `o1.equals(o2) == true`, то желательно, чтобы `o1.compareTo(o2) == 0`, иначе теряется консистентность)

<0 - если o1 должен идти перед o2 (в случаем с числами `o1<o2`, со строками, по алфавиту o1 идёт раньше o2)

Comment: добавьте пояснение, что в скобках у вас примеры выполнения условия. сходу непонятно.

Comment: Также стоит добавить, что категорически рекомендуется, чтобы методы `compareTo` и `equals` были консистентны.