# Сравнение строк на больше, меньше

Tags: java

Не могу найти в `Java` стандартных механизмов для проверки строк на `>`, `<`. Уверен, что где-то они есть...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494097/177499

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `compareTo()`

> В Java compareTo() получает значение 0, если аргумент является строкой
>   лексически равной данной строке; значение меньше 0, если аргумент
>   является строкой лексически большей, чем сравниваемая строка; и
>   значение больше 0, если аргумент является строкой лексически меньшей
>   этой строки

[Пример](http://proglang.su/java/105):

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String str1 = "Я буду хорошим программистом!";
      String str2 = "Я буду хорошим программистом!";
      String str3 = "Я буду хорошим дворником!";

      int result = str1.compareTo(str2);
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str2.compareTo(str3);
      System.out.println(result);

      result = str3.compareTo(str1);
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

> 0
>
> 11
>
> -11

Answer (score 2):

Используйте метод [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Возврщает 0, если строки равны, значения меньше 0, если строка, для которой вызывали метод меньше строки, переданной в параметрах, (по лексиграфическому признаку) и больше нуля - наоброт.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от конкретных обстоятельств используйте String.compareTo, String.compareToIgnoreCase или Collator.compare.