# число больше long (java)

Tags: java, biginteger

в задаче столкнулся с такой необходимостью.
Нужно считать сканером с консоли число больше long. Я так понимаю нужно будет заносить это число в BigIneteger, но каким методом считать сканером не понимаю, или нужно считать как строку и преобразовать, но можно ли преобразовать строку в BigIneteger?

Comment: а стандартный конструктор бигинтежера разве не из строки создает? типа так `BigInteger value = new BigInteger("строкацифр");`

Comment: `new BigInteger(scanner.next())`.

Comment: А чтобы я мог с этим числом операции сравнения делать? (>, <)

Comment: `val1.compareTo(val2)` где `val1`,`val2` - BigInteger, возращает -1,0,1 - меньше, равно, больше

Comment: а если мне нужно сравнивать с конкретным числом? BigInteger > 9223372036854775807

Comment: ну можно создать объект BigInteger на основе этого числа и сравнивать все же бигинтеджеры. Типа `val1.compareTo(new BigInteger("9223372036854775807"))`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте метод `nextBigInteger` класса `Scanner`.

Вот пример:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        BigInteger number = in.nextBigInteger();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

А чтобы преобразовать строку в `BigInteger`, можно так попробовать:

```java
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = in.nextLine();
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(line);

        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям, вычислять не надо, надо только сравнить. А т.к. 9223372036854775807 тоже не помещается в long, то можно и сравнивать строки. Сначала длину, которая  длина больше, то и число больше. Если длины одинаковые, то уже [сравнить лексически строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601429/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5).

Comment: че-то посмотрел пишут в инете 9223372036854775807 - это как раз максимум long, не? не считал )))

Comment: @Андрюха ну может быть, я не смотрел. Но long с BigInteger все равно не получится сравнить, придётся переводить в BigIntegrr  тоже.

Comment: да, 2**63-1=9223372036854775807

Comment: `которая длина больше, то и число больше` - не работает для `01` и `2`.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA не, ну я уж исхожу из того, что ведущих нулей нет.

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо, ваша инфа была полезна для изучения.
мне помогло применение исключений try - catch. то есть в try я проводил сравнение чисел long и ниже, а в исключение уже вывел в строке то что больше long.