# Парсер погоды (Java)

Tags: java, jsoup

**Задача :**

Вывести на экран список из 10 городов с текущей температурой окружающей среды. Список вывести по алфавиту.

Отдельно вывести список городов, где сейчас идёт снег (или дождь, или пасмурно, или солнечно).

Также вести на экран, сколько времени выполнялась программа.

**Мой ход решения :**

Выбрал сайт : http://www.travel.ru/weather/russia/

Подключил библиотеку : jsoup

Не получается :

Вытащить из тега tr имя города и поместить его в переменную.

Вытащить прогноз погоды и поместить его в переменную.

В общем, Хьюстон, у нас проблемы.

**Мой код :**

```
package devjatnadcat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Devjatnadcat1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://travel.ru/weather/russia/").get();

        Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "b-table_row b-forecast");
        trElements.forEach(trElement ->{
            Element 
        });
    }
}
class Article{
    private String url;
    private String name;

    public Article(String url,String name){
        this.url=url;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(){
        this.url=url;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: так а в чем проблема?

Comment: @VartlokНе получается :

Вытащить из тега tr имя города и поместить его в переменную.

Вытащить прогноз погоды и поместить его в переменную.

В общем,Хьюстон,у нас проблемы.

Comment: какой-то подозрительный код внутри лямбды `trElement ->{ Element }` :D

Comment: уточните вопрос. сделайте его более узким. например, как получить содержимое HTML элемента при помощи JSOUP. поставьте метку jsoup.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman вопрос-задача,а использование каких-либо библиотек - это способы решения задачи,я ведь не собираюсь решить эту задачу только с JSOUP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не очень понимаю в чём проблема, но если сделать так:

```
trElements.forEach(trElement ->{
    Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("b-table_cell"); // выбираем элементы по классу b-table_cell
    System.out.print(elementsByClass.get(0).text() + " "); // первая колонка - Город
    // Парсим вторую колонку
    Element element = elementsByClass.get(1);
    String temp = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_temp").text(); // температура
    String precipitation = element.getElementsByClass("b-forecast_description").text(); // осадки
    System.out.println(temp + " " + precipitation);
});
```

То вывод будет:

> Ялта +1 / -1 снег
>   Иркутск -8 / -17 ясно
>   Красная Поляна +4 / 0 возможен дождь
>   Якутск -34 / -36 облачно
>   Мурманск -1 / -4 переменная облачность
>   Выборг +2 / +1 снег
>   Салехард -18 / -25 переменная облачность
>   Южно-Сахалинск -9 / -19 облачно с прояснениями
>   Ростов Великий -4 / -6 облачно
>   Армавир +1 / 0 облачно

Дальше можно идти глубже и разбирать каждую колонку, вытаскивать градусы и осадки отдельно. Про то как работать с JSOUP можно почитать [тут](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

Comment: как отсортировать полученный результат по алфавитному порядку?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров я не знаю какая в у вас в итоге структура данных, но у стрингов есть метод compareTo - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494097/177499

Comment: хорошо,спасибо. По поводу задачи : также нужен вывод сколько времени отработала программа. Знаю два способа System.nanoTime() и system.currenttimemillis() но они выдают большое значение. В какую сторону округлять?

Comment: Лично я всегда считаю через милисекунды. Ну и для 1к+ итераций. И если хотите задайте отдельный вопрос, всё таки СО это база знаний.

Comment: по условию задачи написанной вверху,там есть,что нужно вывести время выполнения)

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров ну так это вопрос неправильно оформлен, один вопрос-один ответ, а не солянка из десятка технических проблем.

Comment: хорошо. Как вытащить осадки и градусы отдельно? Чтобы в первом выводе были "города + температура" а во втором выводе были  те "города + осадки"?

Comment: @МаратЗимнуров обновил ответ, но вы хоть почитайте ссылку, что я вам указал. Посмотрите DOM сайта, который вы парсите. Подумайте, это полезнее, чем просто узнавать правильные ответы.

Comment: сейчас внизу сделаю свой ответ на вопрос ,посмотрите код и дайте ответ в комментарий,как можно отсортировать полученный список городов по алфавиту

Comment: прикрепил свой ответ,посмотрите

Comment: посмотрели код?просто тишина смущает